# Compile Error: Syntax Error caused by code inserting a excel formula

Tags: excel, vba, compiler-errors

This Line of Code causes a Compile Error: Syntax Error
I cant figure out what i have to change. It works fine with other formulas so i think it may be something about the formula.

```
  Range("O2:O" & LastRow).Formula = "=WENN(Q2="";"";WENN(H2*7*Q2<L2;"Möglich";"Prüfen"))"
```

Thanks for help and suggestions

My entire code:

```
    Columns("A:M").Select
    Selection.Replace What:=",", Replacement:=".", LookAt:=xlPart, _
        SearchOrder:=xlByRows, MatchCase:=False, SearchFormat:=False, _
        ReplaceFormat:=False
    Range("N2").Select
    Range("P2:P240023").Select
    Application.CutCopyMode = False
    Selection.ClearContents
    Range("N3").Select
    Range("N3:O24023").Select
    Selection.ClearContents
    Range("N2:O2").Select
    Selection.AutoFill Destination:=Range("N2:O24023")
    Range("N2:O240023").Select
    Columns("A:O").Select
    Columns("A:O").EntireColumn.AutoFit
    Range("C:C,J:J,K:K,M:M").Select
    Range("M1").Activate
    Selection.EntireColumn.Hidden = True
    Rows("2:2").Select
    ActiveWindow.FreezePanes = True

    Range("O2:O" & LastRow).Formula = "=WENN(Q2="";"";WENN(H2*7*Q2<L2;"Möglich";"Prüfen"))"
```

Comment: Try `"=WENN(Q2="""";"""";WENN(H2*7*Q2<L2;""Möglich"";""Prüfen""))"` You need to pad the double quotes.

Comment: Also depending on your regional settings, you may have to use `,` instead of `;`

Comment: Add the English formula so instead of WENN use IF and use , instead of ;

Comment: As far as I know, property `Range.Formula` only admits formulas in english. But Excel is available in many languages. To insert a formula using another language instead of english, I think you should use property `Range.FormulaLocal`. More info in https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.range.formulalocal

Comment: @SiddharthRout Thanks for the suggestion using ; is working since i started using it probably european settings...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you use formulas "" (Empty) should be """" and "test" should be ""test""

Change this:

```
Range("O2:O" & LastRow).Formula = "=WENN(Q2="";"";WENN(H2*7*Q2<L2;"Möglich";"Prüfen"))"
```

To this:

```
Sheet1.Range("O2:O" & LastRow).Formula = "=WENN(Q2="""";"""";WENN(H2*7*Q2<L2,""Möglich"",""Prüfen""))"
```

If needed also change ***";"*** to ***","*** (depends on excel version).

**Full Code:**

```
Option Explicit

Sub test()

    Dim LastRow As Long

    With ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1") '<- Change sheet name if needed

        LastRow = .Cells(.Rows.Count, "O").End(xlUp).Row '<- Change column lf needed. Have in mind that because Lastrow is in the with statement, Lastrow calculation related with the sheet in the with statemet

        .Columns("A:M").Replace What:=",", Replacement:=".", LookAt:=xlPart, _
            SearchOrder:=xlByRows, MatchCase:=False, SearchFormat:=False, _
            ReplaceFormat:=False
        .Range("N3:O24023,P2:P240023").ClearContents '<- ClearContents clear only Contents . if you want to clear everything use .Clear
        .Range("N2:O2").AutoFill Destination:=Range("N2:O24023")
        .Columns("A:O").EntireColumn.AutoFit
        .Range("C:C,J:J,K:K,M:M").EntireColumn.Hidden = True
        Rows("2:2").Select
        ActiveWindow.FreezePanes = True

        .Range("O2:O" & LastRow).Formula = "=IF(Q2="""",IF((H2*7*Q2)<L2,""Möglich"",""Prüfen""))"

    End With

End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, did you remove the & LastRow on purpose? i tried it but im getting the error object required

Comment: No it was for testing purposes. Could you please upload your code in order to get an idea to help?

Comment: I uploade the entire Sub

Comment: Where do you calculate LastRow? i can t see anything

Comment: Range("O2:O" & LastRow). AFter Range its supposed to select everything from cell O2 to the last cell in row O

Comment: @Cedric you have in your code may unnecessary lines of code. i try to fix it. You could try and let me know.

Comment: Yes thats true im reworking an old file so it can be used again. Im mostly improving it and adding new stuff, but since im barely just getting to know vba i dont know alot

Comment: It is working now thanks alot for the help with it. I just have one problem for some eason the formula doesnt get copied until the last row but only around 140 k cells down. I didnt find any difference from the 2 cells where it stops and i cant figure out why but thats for another question i guess

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/191239/discussion-between-error-1004-and-cedric).

Answer (score 3):

The problem is that there aren't enough quotes `"` on the first part of the formula, causing the string to not terminate. Try to change the code like this:

```
Range("O2:O" & lastRow).Formula = "=IF(Q2="""","""",IF(H2*7*Q2<L2,""Möglich"",""Prüfen""))"
```

Or like this if you want to keep your local language formula:

```
Range("O2:O" & lastRow).FormulaLocal = "=WENN(Q2="""";"""";WENN(H2*7*Q2<L2;""Möglich"";""Prüfen""))"
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion after changing the code i now get the error "Runtime Error 1004 the method range of object global failed